# Is it possible to reconfigure a 48v forklift battery bank temporarily to charge with 24v charger?

Tags: batteries, charger

I have a charger that I use for my 24 volt forklift and I also have a 48 volt forklift and I don't have a working charger for it.  Is it possible to somehow use the 24 volt charger to charge the 48 volt battery bank? Someone suggested that it would work without making any changes but I tried and after several hours the charger said the charge was compete but the forklift still said the battery was dead.  I don't think the batteries would have gone completely dead, they were just working recently, but I'm aware that the fact that they were totally discharged may have killed them.  But they aren't showing any sign of a charge and I'm hoping to give it another try.  Is there any possibility of reconfiguring the bank into two 24 volt banks temporarily to be charged with the 24 volt charger? Was my friend correct in saying that the 24 volt charger should have charged the 48 volt battery bank with no changes? I suspected that he wasn't but I'm not sure.

Comment: Strictly from an electrical perspective, you can re-arrange the 48V bank into a 24 V bank and charge it. But there are a whole bunch of pitfalls and dangers. And it may force you to remove the batteries from the forklift, rewire them, then put them back in. I imagine after all that work, it might be better to just wait until you are able to get a working 48V charger.

Answer (score 1):

You could charge first the half bank and then the other half bank. No problem at all.

Since the solution is trivial and it didn't came immediately to you, I have a reason to think that you don't know too much about electrical engineering. Well the forklift battery can be lethal in case of short circuit, so I would suggest you to find somebody that has  at least some knowledge.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqCtpb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Would you advise this as a regular practise - how do you “balance” the SoC of the two halves?

Comment: I do have a basic understanding of DC battery Banks and I have built a few simple ones for other applications so the idea actually did come to me but some local technicians suggested that it might not be a good idea for the aforementioned reasons, I. E. How to balance the state of charge of the two Banks and whether or not it would be feasible to rewire them on a temporary basis just to perform the charging.

Comment: This is why I followed one of their suggestions which was to attempt to charge the entire 48v Bank using the 24 volt charger which to me seemed counterintuitive.

Comment: I do plan to purchase an appropriate 48 volt charger however the forklifts are in a remote location and there is no nearby place to purchase such a charger and considering the fact that the batteries have been deeply discharged, I didn't want to leave them in such a state for a prolonged period, and it's not currently feasible for me to travel to acquire said charger, and the cost for shipping it via Freight is prohibitively expensive due to its massive weight.

Comment: But yes it does look rather Elementary because it's easy to see the beginning and end of the circuit and all of the connections. It looks quite straightforward but the local experts seem to think that it may not be feasible. Hence, my question.

Comment: @SolarMike The balance would be better than using 48V charger, yet better the whole battery would be balanced by charging each individual cell alone with 2V charger.

Comment: Yeah, as long as the OP doesn't goof up, charging the top and bottom halves one at a time is a good idea. They will be balanced enough. Just make sure you put the charging cables in the correct place!

Comment: Those people who suggested charging with 24V, maybe they were just trying to partially revive the batteries. I don't know. I wasn't there and didn't hear all that they said. But if they were under the impression that a 24V charger would charge a 48V battery bank, then I would be very suspicious of any advice they give you in the future.